# Having problem with uploading large excel file however ok to upload small one

Tags: mysql, pandas, flask, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble to upload large (only large, small is ok) file to mySQL using Pandas, sqlAlchemy, in Flask. I am using session so not sure whats the problem. After submitting file it doesn't show any error, but When I checked mySQL database there is nothing. However, if I remove half of the rows from same file, it is uploading.

Comment: Add error log on top - ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py:479: UserWarning: The "b'session'" cookie is too large: the value was 27320 bytes but the header required 26 extra bytes. The final size was 27346 bytes but the limit is 4093 bytes. Browsers may silently ignore cookies larger than this.
  samesite=samesite,```